# LibGDX multiple enemies animations

Tags: libgdx

Hello everyone i have a question about animating multiple enemies on the screen at the same time.

Basically, i figured out how to use the Pool for creating enemies and dispose them after use etc..
All enemies are equal to each other, and all enemies have 3 different animations for creating, moving, destroying.

Everything is working fine, but when i have multiple enemies on screen, they are all animating at the same times, even if they were (obviously) created in different times.

For example, i create 3 enemies, make them moving on the screen and they all have the same frame.. the animation must be the same for all, but i expected that the time when they change frame should be different.

The animations are instantiated inside the Enemy class, so i guess every instance of Enemy must have its own animation.

This is how i draw them in the Renderer class:

```
private void drawEnemies(float runTime) {
    enemyArrayLen = catta.activeEnemies.size;
    for (int i = enemyArrayLen; --i >= 0;) {
        currentEnemyAnimation = catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getCurrentAnimation();
        batcher.draw(
            currentEnemyAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getX(),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getY(),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getWidth() / 2.0f,
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getHeight() / 2.0f,
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getWidth(),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getHeight(),
            1,
            1,
            0
        );
    }
}
```

Enemies are stored in the catta.activeEnemies array.

currentEnemyAnimation is a "support" variable in which i put the Enemy in every cicle of the for cicle.

This is how i initialize an Enemy:

```
public void init(float posX, float posY, int width, int height) {
    this.position.set(posX,  posY);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.alive = true;
    this.enemyRunTime = 0;
    this.creationTime = 0.8f;
    this.destructionTime = 0.8f;
    this.crea_Animation = AssetLoader.enemy_creaAnimation;
    this.crea_Animation.setFrameDuration(this.creationTime / 4);
    this.mo_Animation = AssetLoader.enemy_moAnimation;
    this.des_Animation = AssetLoader.enemy_desAnimation;
    this.des_Animation.setFrameDuration(this.destructionTime / 4);
    this.enemyState = EnemyState.CREATING;
    ...
```

Maybe it's all a runTime and delta matter?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED, i had to pass the enemyRunTime to batcher when drawing each enemy, instead of the global runTime.. like this:

```
private void drawEnemies(float runTime) {
    enemyArrayLen = catta.activeEnemies.size;
    for (int i = enemyArrayLen; --i >= 0;) {
        currentEnemyAnimation = catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getCurrentAnimation();
        batcher.draw(
            currentEnemyAnimation.getKeyFrame(catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getEnemyRunTime()),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getX(),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getY(),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getWidth() / 2.0f,
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getHeight() / 2.0f,
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getWidth(),
            catta.activeEnemies.get(i).getHeight(),
            1,
            1,
            0
        );
    }
}
```

Now each enemy animates independently from the others